# i need help resolving this java code

Tags: java

I have to write a complete Java program that prompts the user for a series of numbers to determine the smallest value entered.  Before the program terminates, display the smallest value. I have to use this code and to complete the information to run the program:

This is the code:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int smallest = 9999999;
    String user_Input;
    boolean quit = false;

    System.out.println("This program finds the smallest number"
        + " in a series of numbers");
    System.out.println("When you want to exit, type Q");

    while(…………..)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        user_Input = keyboard.next();
        if(user_Input.equals("Q")……….. user_Input.equals("q"))
        {
            quit = true;
        }
        ………..
        {
            int user_Number = Integer.parseInt(user_Input);

            if(……………………)
                smallest = user_Number;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: That's a terrible title. Your title should summarize the issue. Please edit it to reflect the actual problem you're asking about.

Comment: A better title might be: "who's willing to do my homework for free?".

Comment: What exactly do you need help with then? What part of this code is giving you issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This just reads and tries to parse the number, if it fails, then it just move on to the while loop's guard.

Also you should try to use Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of a random number. Just in case someone decides to actually use the max value; don't assume that 9,999,999 or how ever many 9's you want is the max as

1. You will actually surpass the max value and cause an error
2. Not actually reach the max value
3. Magic Numbers are bad

For more info on max value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
String input = "";

System.out.println("This program find the smallest number" 
    + " in a series of numbers");
System.out.println("When you want to exit, type Q");

while (!input.toLowerCase().equals("q")) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    input = keyboard.next();
    try {
        int numb = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if (numb < smallest) 
            smallest = numb;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Maybe check for other random strings here?
        // If you expect only "Q" or a number, then no need
    }
}

System.out.println("Smallest number: " + smallest);
System.exit(0);
```